# 02 Honda civic LX battery drain

Tags: honda, battery, civic, alternator

Put a new alternator in and it's charging I believe I took the negative cable off and it said running but while driving is sputters dies out and then especially when the Sun goes down when it's evening time and it doesn't hold a charge or it's charging I believe but it's not want to start back up like battery is dead

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the battery isn't charged up like it should be. Take the battery out of the car and fully charge it. Once you're done, put it in the car, start it, then check the voltage at the battery with a multimeter. If it's 13+ vdc and steady, you're in pretty good shape. If it's 13+ volts or less and dropping, then the alternator is still at fault.

Also, once the battery is fully charged, install the battery and turn the lights on for a few seconds. Once this is done, check the voltage on the battery. If it is not above 12 vdc, then you have a battery issue. You'd need to get it load tested.

As a side note, do NOT disconnect the battery while the engine is running. This is a good way ruin electronics in your vehicle. This USED to be a way to check generators, but doing it in a vehicle with an alternator can cause issues.